# jQuery AJAX post отправка и вывод php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Есть файл graph.php

```js
var weekday = new Array('Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб');
var table = $(".table-hover");
var result = [];

function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault()
  }
}
$("#gen").click(function() {
  table.empty();
  var rows = $("#rows").val() - 1;
  var date = new Date($("#from").val());
  for (var i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
    var day, month, year;
    month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    month = ('0' + month).slice(-2);
    year = date.getFullYear();
    day = date.getDate();
    day = ('0' + day).slice(-2);
    table.append("<tr><td>" + weekday[date.getDay()] + "</td><td>" + [day, month, year].join(",") + "</td><td><select></select></td><td><select></select></td><td><select></select></td></tr>");
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
  }
  $("select").append('<option value="1">X</option><option value="2">Start up</option><option value="3">Base</option><option value="4">Advanced</option><option value="5">VIP</option>');
  return date, rows
});
$("#save").click(function() {
  $("select").each(function(indx) {
    result[indx] = $(this).val()
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "engine/ajax/graph-post.php",
    data: {
      vals: result
    },
    success: function() {
      $('#save').css('color', 'lime');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table-fill">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">График занятий</th>
      <th>14-15:00</th>
      <th>18-19:00</th>
      <th>19-20:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">

  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="result">
  <span>Сколько дней выводим?</span>
  <span>Дата начала</span>
  <input id="rows" type="text" onkeypress="validate(event)" value="14" placeholder="Сколько дней выводим?">
  <input id="from" type="date" value="2017-03-13" placeholder="Дата начала">
  <input id="gen" type="button" value="Сгенерировать">
  <input id="save" type="button" value="Сохранить">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Который выводит и выполняет jQuery код генерации таблицы исходя из введенных данных.
С помощью:

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "engine/ajax/graph-post.php",
    data: { vals : result },
    success: function() {
        $('#save').css('color','lime');
    }
});
```

я отправляю сгенерированный массив result[] на обработку в файл graph-post.php , его содержимое:

```
$tdVars = $_REQUEST['vals'];
$json = file_get_contents('graph.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$json[] = $tdVars;
$json = json_encode($json);
file_put_contents('graph.json', $json);
echo $json;
```

А этот файл в свою очередь должен вывести данные в другом месте.
Но на сколько я понял, я все делаю неверно.
Мне нужно либо третий файл создать который будет получать данные из graph.json и выводить в нужном месте. Либо еще в первом кодировать jQuery переменные в json строки и с помощью php сразу же записывать их в файл graph.json , а вторым файлом по выполнению, читать json файл и выводить.
Помогите подобрать оптимальный метод, а то уже голова вскипает от этого кода.
Да и еще по выводу json файла мне нужно обратно в jquery переменные вернуть массив.

Comment: попробуйте сформировать то что вам требуеться, зачем вам фаил вообще?

Comment: Требуется изъять из jQuery кода значения переменных и с помощью php отправить их в другой файл на вывод (записать в те же jQuery переменные).

Comment: ладно а какую задачу вы таким образом пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Нужно из одного места (скажем из админки) получить переменные которые получаться в результате выполнения jQuery кода и записать их в те же переменные (jQuery) только на сайте.
Передать значения и массивы возможно только с помощью сервера.
Вот и вопрос. Как?

Comment: Попахивает костылём каким-то. Почему график не реализовать через базу? Сейчас Вы дополняете каждый раз файл, и он у Вас будет расти  и расти. Вам надо иметь какой-то идентификатор, там user_id, и сохранять всё это дело в базе. И вытаскивать из базы по айдишнику, а не полностью всё

Comment: Если вы всё таки решите делать через файл, то в любом случае Вам нужен идентификатор, и Вы должны будете сохранять json файл по айдишнику. Допустим user_id = 1 и вы сохраняете файл 1.json c настройками графика.

Comment: Вот тут я создавал сам скрипт: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peWOBb?editors=0110
Так вот этот результат будет в админке, на сайте будет такая же таблица, только select'ы внутри ячеек будут заменены на <a>
Нужно передать 3 переменные (массив со значениями select'ov, количество <tr> строк rows и начальная дата - date) и тогда я смогу.
То есть в админке заполнил данные, нажал кнопку сохранить (по нажатию переменные отправились на сам сайт) и по загрузке страницы сгенерировалась такая же страница.